# How can I remove the borders/control box from a WPF Form?

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, styles

In Windows Form, I would modify the FormBorderStyle property in the Properties pane.

Any help?

Comment: Can you post some XAML markup for the form and perhaps what you've tried already?

Comment: I can't post any code because I haven't done anything. I don't know what the property is to disable resizing and control box removal. I want the form to act a splash screen. No borders should be seen.

Comment: FYI in .NET 3.5 SP1 you can have a bitmap as a splash screen without needing to create a window for it.  This also helps it display faster as it doesn't need to load so much of WPF or construct the application instance.  To do this, add a bitmap file to your project and set the Build Action to SplashScreen, or use the System.Windows.SplashScreen class (samples in MSDN).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `WindowStyle` to `None`, and `ResizeMode` to `NoResize` (either in XAML or through the Properties pane).

Comment: That removed the control box, but I can still resize the form and a blue little border is seen. Thanks a bunch for your help! The idea I want is for a Splash screen so only I set an Image to occupy the whole form and I want nothing else displayed. Any help?

Comment: Good catch!  Sorry about that: edited to add how to get rid of the border (ResizeMode).

Answer (score 5):

Creating a splash screen is actually supported by the .NET framework, check out this form post on [social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8dd49fd0-9cc9-43c6-b285-6f119ab8a32e?prof=required) which points you to this walkthrough for the [most performant .NET splash screen.](http://blogs.msdn.com/jgoldb/archive/2007/12/10/splash-screen-to-improve-wpf-application-perceived-cold-startup-performance.aspx)

You can designate an image as a splashscreen using the properties window.